# How to reduce memory consumption of an autoresize textview?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an autoresize-textview, which does all i want, but it consumes a lot of memory, since i have many of them. Restarting my app leads to out of memory-errors.

What could be the most memory-consuming elements and is it possible to release some memory? Is it maybe possible to recycle some of its members (mTextRect,mAvailableSpaceRect,mPaint) ?

```
public class AutoResizeTextview extends TextView
{
    private interface SizeTester
    {
        /**
         * 
         * @param suggestedSize
         *            Size of text to be tested
         * @param availableSpace
         *            available space in which text must fit
         * @return an integer < 0 if after applying {@code suggestedSize} to
         *         text, it takes less space than {@code availableSpace}, > 0
         *         otherwise
         */
        public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSpace);
    }

    private RectF               mTextRect           = new RectF();

    private RectF               mAvailableSpaceRect;

    private SparseIntArray      mTextCachedSizes;

    private TextPaint           mPaint;

    private float               mMaxTextSize;

    private float               mSpacingMult        = 1.0f;

    private float               mSpacingAdd         = 0.0f;

    private float               mMinTextSize        = 3;

    private int                 mWidthLimit;

    private static final int    NO_LINE_LIMIT       = -1;
    private int                 mMaxLines;

    private boolean             mEnableSizeCache    = true;
    private boolean             mInitiallized;

    public AutoResizeTextview(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public AutoResizeTextview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public AutoResizeTextview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        mPaint = new TextPaint(getPaint());
        mMaxTextSize = getTextSize();
        mAvailableSpaceRect = new RectF();
        mTextCachedSizes = new SparseIntArray();
        if (mMaxLines == 0)
        {
            // no value was assigned during construction
            mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        }
        mInitiallized = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(final CharSequence text, BufferType type)
    {
        super.setText(text, type);
        adjustTextSize(text.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextSize(float size)
    {
        mMaxTextSize = size;
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxLines(int maxlines)
    {
        super.setMaxLines(maxlines);
        mMaxLines = maxlines;
        reAdjust();
    }

    public int getMaxLines()
    {
        return mMaxLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSingleLine()
    {
        super.setSingleLine();
        mMaxLines = 1;
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSingleLine(boolean singleLine)
    {
        super.setSingleLine(singleLine);
        if (singleLine)
        {
            mMaxLines = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        }
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLines(int lines)
    {
        super.setLines(lines);
        mMaxLines = lines;
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextSize(int unit, float size)
    {
        Context c = getContext();
        Resources r;

        if (c == null)
            r = Resources.getSystem();
        else
            r = c.getResources();
        mMaxTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, size, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult)
    {
        super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
        mSpacingMult = mult;
        mSpacingAdd = add;
    }

    /**
     * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
     * 
     * @param minTextSize
     */
    public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize)
    {
        mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
        reAdjust();
    }

    private void reAdjust()
    {
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    private void adjustTextSize(String string)
    {
        if (!mInitiallized)
        {
            return;
        }
        int startSize = (int) mMinTextSize;
        int heightLimit = getMeasuredHeight() - getCompoundPaddingBottom() - getCompoundPaddingTop();
        mWidthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight();
        mAvailableSpaceRect.right = mWidthLimit;
        mAvailableSpaceRect.bottom = heightLimit;
        super.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, efficientTextSizeSearch(startSize, (int) mMaxTextSize, mSizeTester, mAvailableSpaceRect));
    }

    private final SizeTester    mSizeTester = new SizeTester()
    {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSPace)
        {
            mPaint.setTextSize(suggestedSize);
            String text = getText().toString();
            boolean singleline = getMaxLines() == 1;
            // if (singleline) {    //my comment-out
            // mTextRect.bottom = mPaint.getFontSpacing();  //my comment-out
            // mTextRect.right = mPaint.measureText(text);  //my comment-out
            // } else { //my comment-out
            StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, mPaint, mWidthLimit, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult,
                    mSpacingAdd, true);
            // return early if we have more lines
            if (getMaxLines() != NO_LINE_LIMIT && layout.getLineCount() > getMaxLines())
            {
                return 1;
            }
            mTextRect.bottom = layout.getHeight();
            int maxWidth = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++)
            {
                if (maxWidth < layout.getLineWidth(i))
                {
                    maxWidth = (int) layout.getLineWidth(i);
                }
            }
            mTextRect.right = maxWidth;
            // }    //my comment-out

            mTextRect.offsetTo(0, 0);
            if (availableSPace.contains(mTextRect))
            {
                // may be too small, don't worry we will find the best match
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                // too big
                return 1;
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Enables or disables size caching, enabling it will improve performance
     * where you are animating a value inside TextView. This stores the font
     * size against getText().length() Be careful though while enabling it as 0
     * takes more space than 1 on some fonts and so on.
     * 
     * @param enable
     *            enable font size caching
     */
    public void enableSizeCache(boolean enable)
    {
        mEnableSizeCache = enable;
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    private int efficientTextSizeSearch(int start, int end, SizeTester sizeTester, RectF availableSpace)
    {
        if (!mEnableSizeCache)
        {
            return binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
        }
        String text = getText().toString();
        int key = text == null ? 0 : text.length();
        int size = mTextCachedSizes.get(key);
        if (size != 0)
        {
            return size;
        }
        size = binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
        mTextCachedSizes.put(key, size);
        return size;
    }

    private static int binarySearch(int start, int end, SizeTester sizeTester, RectF availableSpace)
    {
        int lastBest = start;
        int lo = start;
        int hi = end - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        while (lo <= hi)
        {
            mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
            int midValCmp = sizeTester.onTestSize(mid, availableSpace);
            if (midValCmp < 0)
            {
                lastBest = lo;
                lo = mid + 1;
            }
            else
                if (midValCmp > 0)
                {
                    hi = mid - 1;
                    lastBest = hi;
                }
                else
                {
                    return mid;
                }
        }
        // make sure to return last best
        // this is what should always be returned
        return lastBest;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int before, final int after)
    {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldwidth, int oldheight)
    {
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);
        if (width != oldwidth || height != oldheight)
        {
            reAdjust();
        }
    }
}
```

thx in advance

Comment: At what point do you receive the out of memory errors? When you are closing the app (perhaps attempting to write state to persistent memory?), or when you open the app again after a restart (out of memory caused by creating a lot of text views)? Just having a lot of text views should *not* cause out of memory issues, since devices have a *lot* of memory relative to the memory you need to store some text.

Comment: Crashing after restarting and trying to create 3600 TextViews (I know its a little extreme) and adding them to a ViewPager . They consume 16,3 mb just before that.

Comment: Can I ask what in the coder's heavens you need 3600 TextViews for? That sounds more than just a little extreme.

Comment: Thank you Erik, i dont really need them. I create layouts/views in this app dynamically and wanted to penetrate the system with heavy load to find out faster what potentially could be a memory leak. There is probably no real issue except too many views. Unfortunately the garbage collector doesnt release ressources after onDestroy  immediately. So i wonder if i should release them myself just to be safe. All i tried is not really satisfying though :(